# How to show two placeholders for values of a Kivy slider at all times (show 01 instead of 1)?

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy, kivy-language

I'm using three Kivy sliders to create a timer. The user specifies the hour, minute, and AM/PM using the sliders. I would like the value of the slider that corresponds to minutes to show 01 vs. 1 so that 5:01 AM doesn't appear as 5:1 AM. How would I go about doing this? I've linked a picture of the GUI and the code.

Sliders with timer value
https://i.stack.imgur.com/YVDMs.png

Kivy code for three sliders and label that shows hours and minutes
https://i.stack.imgur.com/2suus.png

Comment: Instead of providing images of code, please consider copy-pasting your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can extend `Slider` to create a class that has the string that you want as a property that can be used in your `kv`. Here is an example of how to do this:

```
class MySlider(Slider):
    val_str = StringProperty('00')  # new property that contains the desired string

    def on_value(self, slider, new_value):
        # update val_str property
        self.val_str = '{:02d}'.format(int(new_value))
```

then use the new class in your kv:

```
MySlider:
    id: monSliderM1
    min: 0
    max: 59
    step: 1
    orientation: 'horizontal'
    size_hint: 0.3, 0.1
    pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'top':0.95}
Label:
    text: monSliderM1.val_str
    size_hint: 0.3, 0.1
    pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'top': 0.75}
```

You can use multiple instance of `MySlider` and combine their `val_str` properties by simple string concatenation. Here is an updated `kv` using two instances:

```
MySlider:
    id: monSliderH1
    min: 0
    max: 12
    step: 1
    orientation: 'horizontal'
    size_hint: 0.3, 0.1
    pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'top':0.95}
MySlider:
    id: monSliderM1
    min: 0
    max: 59
    step: 1
    orientation: 'horizontal'
    size_hint: 0.3, 0.1
    pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'top':0.85}
Label:
    text: monSliderH1.val_str + ':' + monSliderM1.val_str
    size_hint: 0.3, 0.1
    pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'top': 0.75}
```

Comment: Label:
            text: str(monSliderH1.value)+':'+str(round(monSliderM1.value)) I'm using the previous to show the time. Is there a way to show the hour and minutes together like I am above using the code you've given me? Will I just have to make two separate labels for hours and minutes?

Comment: I don't mind making two separate labels. The only problem is that when the hour value switches from 1 to 2 digits the hour display moves. Not that big of a problem, just looks ugly when the labels are placed specifically so times are shown correctly.

Comment: Everything is sorted out now. Thanks, John. I appreciate it.